# Perl - How to save to file and then recall data

Tags: perl

This is my first post so please be gentle.
Here is the problem I am writing a script for:

### The Echo Program

Write a Perl script which copies the input to the output adding `->` to the front and `<-` to the end of each line. It then reports the number lines, the length of the longest line, and the total number of bytes in the original input. Be careful to handle line terminators correctly. The length of a line should not include its terminator (i.e., newline character).

Also note that the total size figure may differ between Windows and Unix systems, as the children of DOS use two characters to represent the line terminator, while Unix uses one.

Use chomp to trim the terminator from the line when needed. You might also be interested to know that the built-in function length takes the length of a string.

The program should continue to prompt for input and display the output after no input is entered (hitting the Enter key without any data). The program should use a loop to calculate the following: o Number of lines read o Longest line encountered (number of characters) o Total characters read Programming Hints • The program will need to use a loop and use the length function.

Example of output

---

| Welcome to the Echo Program |

---

This program will echo your input.

Enter a line of text. Terminate your input by hitting the Enter key.

```
> Hi there.

> This is Fred.

> Who are you? >

Here is the text you entered:

-----------------------------

->Hi there.<-

->This is Fred.<-

->Who are you?<-

3 lines, longest 13 characters, 34 bytes total.
```

The script I wrote works for everything except echoing the text back.  This is our first week using Perl and I am stumped.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $line_count = 0;
my $longest_line = 0;
my $total_bytes = 0;

print "-----------------------------------\n";
print "Welcome to the Echo Program\\n";
print "-----------------------------------\n";
open (my $fh, ">", "new.txt") or die "Can't open > test.txt: $!";

print"This program will echo your input.\n\n";
print "Enter a line of text. Terminate your input by hitting the Enter key.\n";
while (1) {
print "> ";
my $text = <STDIN>;
chomp($text);
print $fh ($text);

my $line_length = length($text);

    $longest_line = $line_length if $line_length > $longest_line;

    $total_bytes += length($text);

    $line_count++;
last if $text eq '';
print "->" . $text . "<-\n";

}

print "Here is the text that you entered:\n";
print "----------------------------------\n";
open ($fh, "<", "new.txt");
while(<$fh>){
print "->" . $text . "<-\n";
}

print "$line_count lines, longest $longest_line characters, $total_bytes bytes total.\\n";
```

Comment: I fixed a bunch of stray escapes in the code. In markdown with indented code, you shouldn't need to escape anything.

Answer (score 3):

First, when you look in *new.txt*, do you see the text that you expect?

I think I'd make some slight modifications. First, you have the "until there's no more input" specification. That's typically just this:

```
while( <> ) {
    ...
    }
```

That shortcut code is actually `while( defined($_= <ARGV>) )`. The `readline` (which is what `<>` is) returns undef when it's exhausted input, so the `while` breaks the loop itself. I tend to think that a blank line (just hitting return) is input, so I wouldn't stop for that.

Instead of stopping at a blank line, a Control-D (or Control-Z on Windows) ends input, causing the `<>` to return undef.

Next, you are saving the output to a file but also printing it to standard output at the same time. There are two `print` statements in your `while`. You don't have unbuffered output (and Perl buffers by default), so some of your output will come out while you are still sending input.  You probably don't want that.

One way to go involves merely building up a string to print later once you'll received all the input. This is not attractive if you are going to process large input though (for whatever value of large you like) because you have to store it all in memory. For small output, like in situations where you are writing toy program s to practice something, you might do this:

```
my $grand_output;
my( $lines, $chars, $longest );
while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    $lines++;
    $chars += length; # bytes and chars not necessarily the same!
    $longest = length if length > $longest;
    
    $grand_output .= "-> $_ <-\n";
    }

print $grand_output;
print ...; # your summary info
```

Note that I use the topic variable `$_`, which is the default variable for `chomp` and `length` (and many other things). Not a big deal if you don't like that just yet.

For much larger output, writing to a file is fine, but then write only to the file, not to both the file and standard out:

```
my $filename = 'new.txt';
open my $fh, '>', $filename or die ...;

my( $lines, $chars, $longest );
while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    $lines++;
    $chars += length; # bytes and chars not necessarily the same!
    $longest = length if length > $longest;
    
    print $fh "-> $_ <-\n";
    }

close $fh; # close will flush all buffered output

open my $in_fh, '<', $filename or die ...;
while(<$in_fh>) { print } # uses $_ again

print ...; # summary stuff
```

I think once you clean up a program a bit to decide how you are doing things, some of your problems will work out. It's often that programs betray several discarded ideas as we edit them to try new things without removing all vestiges of discarded ideas.

Comment: "_It's often that programs betray several discarded ideas as we edit them to try new things without removing all vestiges of discarded ideas._"  -- oh yeah.  That's an extremely useful note, I think.  Often a source of tricky bugs and misleading code comments.